# Db2 pull docker image and Trial version Db2 Binary comparison

Tags: db2

I have a Db2 11.5 Trial Version image for installing db2 on RHEL7. I have no connectivity with the internet where docker installed and I want to configure db2 on docker with that 11.5 Trial Version image.

Is there any limitation to use only docker certified image for dockerization?.

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement that you use IBM's docker images when running Db2 in Docker. You can absolutely build your own Docker images from the standard installable code.

However, are you aware that you can "export" Docker images to  using `docker save` and "import" them using `docker import`?  This is certainly one way you could get IBM's official docker images on to a machine that does not have direct internet access.

Comment: yes I'm aware of export and import feature but not worked technically.. thanks Ian i'll try to create Docker image with standard code